# Charged particle singularity

Tags: black-holes, electrons, singularities, protons

Is it possible to manipulate magnetic/electric fields, similar to magnetic confinement technologies/penning traps, to compress charged particles into black holes?

Comment: No. The highest compression achievable on low energy matter to date would probably come from using a nuclear explosive as the energy source, and even that is tens of orders of magnitude away from the density of a black hole (which is not constant, by the way, small black holes are far more dense than large ones).  The best experimental hope to make small black holes from high energy particles are accelerators, but sadly, since nature doesn't seem to make them in cosmic ray events, we are probably nowhere close to making them ourselves, yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take two protons, they have a mass of about $3.34\times10^{-27}$ kg.

The "Schwarzschild radius" of a two-proton black hole is given by $2GM/c^2 = 5 \times 10^{-54}$ m ! i.e. you have to get the protons closer together than this.
Even ignoring that protons have a radius of $10^{-15}$ m and that there would be an enormous repulsive strong nuclear force to overcome, then just 
consider the uncertainty principle. If $\Delta x = 10^{-54}$ m, then $\Delta p = 10^{20}$ kg/m/s, and the proton energies would be of order $10^{28}$ J.

The highest proton energies achievable in the LHC are $10^{-6}$ J, so 34 orders of magnitude short.

However, CERN did put out a press release to reassure the general public!
http://press.web.cern.ch/backgrounders/safety-lhc

There are various "non-standard" models that suggest such mini black-holes could be produced, but even if they were, they should decay via Hawking radiation almost instantaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, yes. Practically, no. In order to create a singularity you would have to compress mass so that it would have zero volume, and thus an indeterminate density. We simply do not have the capabilities to produce such results on our own.

Edit: Density would approach infinity as the volume approaches zero.

Comment: Why do you say "zero volume"?

Comment: Density is inversely proportional to volume. The limit as volume approaches zero is infinity. Because a singularity has infinite density it must have zero volume. I guess it could alternatively have infinite mass, but that's not possible as far as I know, and it's also just my speculation.

Comment: OK, but you don't need to compress things to *infinite* density to form a black hole. You just need to get them inside their event horizon.

Comment: The main point is that they exist in nature, so theoretically it can be made in a lab. Whether we have the capabilities to do that is another story.

Comment: This is starting to get a little beyond my knowledge, but from my understanding an event horizon is just a point where anything, even light, will be pulled into the singularity (the thing with infinite density). So in order to have an event horizon one must also have a singularity. Again this is starting to get a little beyond me.

Comment: Correction: you do only have to compress something to smaller than its Schwarzschild radius. After that the mass would compress itself into a single point.